# How do I send a dropdown selection in Rails through a post and persist that choice in a session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, session, post, cookies

I am trying to add what should be a simple feature to a Rails site. There is to be a dropdown menu to select what timezone you want times to be displayed for. Once you have selected the timezone, that selection needs to now persist so during that session, any time values for that user that is displayed is in that timezone.

I already have a nice function that my date formatting goes through in a helper module for the ApplicationController where I can apply the timezone and it is automatically applied to all dates displayed. However, a problem I am having is that while I need this data to be sent via POST, I also need to not be reliant on some kind of backend storage to make the select persist. The nature of the site I am doing this for is more or less just a frontend for multiple services so it has no databases of its own. It just makes service calls and displays the data received. This becomes a problem because most of the examples I've seen of session usage compares the session values to model values extended from ActiveRecord. On this site, ActiveRecord isn't even used.

I realize the two things might be irrelevant, but it makes the learning process a bit harder when all the example code compares cookie data to model data when I effectively had no persistent model. Also I still don't quite understand the "Rails Magic" that determines what gets forwarded through in the params hash.

So is there a simple way to have a dropdown selection that just stores the selection in a cookie and future renders for that user can be based on that cookie information without comparing the cookie data to some persistent model data?

Edit: A commenter asked if there is a reason why AJAX can't be used. The answer is that there is no reason other than that I have never used AJAX before, so I would probably need some explanation to make it work. I thought AJAX was just a way to make queries without leaving the page, but the page needs to reload anyways after a selection is made, and more importantly it should re-render the same page that it was on previously with the new settings.

Comment: Can't you just use ajax to send that value to a controller, and save it like `session[:drop_down_val] = params[:drop_down]`?

Comment: It's possible, but I haven't touched AJAX before. I'm pretty much a dev that learned Ruby for the sake of Ruby, and not Rails, but now work is dictating I get into Rails. So I know Ruby, MVC, Rails basics, XHTML, and CSS, but AJAX, JSON, Javascript, and jQuery are still new to me.

Comment: You don't have to use AJAX to use the session variable (although I would suggest getting to know the AJAX goodness that comes with rails).  Once you've gotten the form submit working, use the result to set `session[:time_zone]` and then refer to it like that in your helper method.  It should persist well enough.

Comment: Well how good is your JS? You could set a cookie with the timezone, then read and update the timestamps using JS.